# Euler-Maclaurin summation formula

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

> Show that if $f(x)$ tends to zero monotonically as $x$ increases without limit, and is continuous for $x>0$, and if the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)$ diverges, then $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ ~ $\int_1^nf(x)dx$.

I think this problem is about the E-M summation formula.
I tried to use it but I could not get it.
Would you give me a hint?

Comment: What does E-M say about the difference between the summation and the integral? How does that difference depend on $n$ and given that f(n) tends to zero, what does that imply for the limit of $n$ to infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is considerably simpler than EM summation. It's basically the integral test for series divergence. The fact that $f$ is monotonic allows you to wedge the integral between a sum of $f$ as a Riemann sum with values taken either at the left endpoint or the right of each integer.

Comment: No. it is not just about the integral test.
f is monotonic but f does not go to zero as x>infinity because the sum of series diverges.
we cannot say f is bounded > we can not assure to use Riemann integral

Comment: so, Would you think about this problem in the sense of Number Theory? Thanks:)

Comment: Look at the proof technique in the integral test. You'll see that the order of growth of the sum and integral are the same.